# How to fix objects getting stuck in collisions

Tags: java, collision-detection

In a java game I am making, I have a player and a wall tile. When the player moves forward, it checks if it collides with the wall in this code:

```
player.moveForward2(playerSpeed); //moves player forward
            
for (int i = 1; i <=100; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <=50; j++) {
        map1.map[(int) (i-1)][(int) (j-1)].getRect(); //gets rectangle from object on screen
        player.getRect();
        
        if (player.r.intersects(map1.map[(int) (i-1)][(int) (j-1)].r)) { //checks if player is intersecting rectangle after moving
            if (map1.map[(int) (i-1)][(int) (j-1)].id == 3) { //checks that player isn't able to pass through this tile
                player.moveBackward2(playerSpeed); // moves back if space cannot be moved into
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The problem is when it moves into the rectangle, it gets stuck and can't move in any direction. The method is meant to allow it to move into the rectangle and slide against it without getting stuck on it. The player is centered on the screen and it is the other tiles moving, if that means anything.

Comment: lots of unknowns are here. please share details of the methods what they are doing and **nit:** why you are typecasting `(int) (i-1)` ?? both `i` and `j` are already defined as `int`.

Comment: @roottraveller It first runs the `moveForward2()` method in player, which changes the coordinates stored in the player, which affects where the tiles are drawn. It iterates through the rest of the code for every tile, first getting a rectangle around the player and the tile specified by the for loops, then testing to see if the rectangles intersect. if they do, it moves the player the opposite way. As for the typecasting, that was a mistake, I had copied the loops from a previous method where they were necessary.

Comment: still not very clear.  `player.getRect();` what does it do? does it return some value? can you update with a proper problem statement?